# mysql select with if condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, function

I have a function in Mysql that is called like this:

```
  DB::raw("count_adults(rooms.id) as adults"),
```

count_adults is this:

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE adults INT;

    SELECT  
     count(*) INTO adults 
    FROM 
     clients 
    WHERE 
     clients.room_id = r_id 
        and (age >= 18 
        or age = 0);
            RETURN adults;
    END
```

However I want to if this query returns no results(0) do another select or function, like this:

```
   SELECT count(*) INTO adults  FROM client_room, clients    
WHERE client_id = clients.id and client_room.room_id = r_id and (age >18 or age = 0)
```

Can I create a if condition? IN the php code? Or in the query? Something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM clients WHERE clients.room_id = r_id) 


BEGIN

DECLARE adults INT;

    SELECT  
        count(*) INTO adults 
    FROM 
        clients 
    WHERE 
        clients.room_id = r_id 
        and (age >= 18 
        or age = 0);

   RETURN adults;
END
ELSE 

BEGIN
DECLARE adults INT;
SELECT count(*) INTO adults 
FROM 
client_room, clients
WHERE 
client_id = clients.id and client_room.room_id = r_id 
and (age >18 
or age = 0);

END
```

I have tried this and it seems to work:

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE adults INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO adults
    FROM clients
    WHERE clients.room_id = r_id
     and (age >= 18 or age = 0);

    RETURN IF( adults>0, adults, (SELECT count(*) FROM client_room, clients
         WHERE client_id = clients.id
         and client_room.room_id = r_id)
             );

   END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) in the query, e.g.:

```
CASE
  WHEN function1() > 0
    THEN function1()
  WHEN function2() > 0
    THEN function2()
  ELSE
    0
END
```

That will evaluate to the value returned from `function1()` if it is larger than 0. If it's not but the value returned by `function2()` is larger then 0, then this is taken. Otherwise it's 0.

Instead of `function1()`, `function2()` etc. a column, subquery (that is, if it returns a scalar), literal, etc. can be used. And of course it can be changed to more or less conditions.

Comment: This would be something like:
BEGIN
CASE
WHEN count_adults() > 0
THEN count_adults ()
WHEN count_adulst1() >0
THEN count_adults1()
 ELSE
    0
END

And in php I would call this function that has the case, like: check_members?

Comment: @Mary: That `CASE` looks correct to me as far as I understand your demand. I'm not sure what you mean by calling "this function", as a query technically isn't a PHP function... put that `CASE` in the query in that place where you want the count. Say, if your query was `SELECT count_adults() FROM table;` replace "count_adults()" with your `CASE`. And use the resulting query in PHP as you'd have done it with the original query. Hope that helps.